# Remove invisible <br> from within double quotes with Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have the output of a csv file that I opened it in Notepad ++. I got this output through an api call. The example below is toy data but similar to the original one.

```
id,name,description
2341,Example,"Example with no double quotes"
4567,Second Example,"Example with double quotes
But the line breaks"
```

The first entry occupies only one line but the second one two, since the line breaks.
From where I got the data, in the description for the second line, there was a `<br>` between the words 'quotes' and 'But'. In the csv output and view through notepad++, this character is not visible but the line breaks.

I used the following code to fix it:

```
$text=(Get-Content $filepath -Raw) -replace  '([^,]")(\s*\r\n\s*)+("[^,])',"`$1`n`$3" -replace '\r\n',''
```

But the result is the same as above.

Desirable outcome is the below:

```
id,name,description
2341,Example,"Example with no double quotes"
4567,Second Example,"Example with double quotes But the line breaks"
```

where the `<br>` character is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object oriented solution is to use `Import-Csv` or `ConvertFrom-Csv`:

```bash
Import-Csv $filepath | ForEach-Object {
    $_.description = $_.description -replace '\r?\n', ' '
    $_
} | ConvertTo-Csv
```

Above example works because you know it's the `.description` property the one that needs to be updated, however, if you didn't know / wanted to handle all columns from your CSV, you would need to iterate over each property of each object:

```
Import-Csv $filepath | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
        if($property.Value -match '\r?\n') {
            $property.Value = $property.Value -replace '\r?\n', ' '
        }
    }

    $_
} | ConvertTo-Csv
```

Comment: It works. But if I want to to apply the same solution to all the columns in the csv, how would I do this ? From what I understand, the `ForEach-Object` uses specific column names. If I want to loop over multiple csvs. how can I apply the same principle for all columns, irrespective of the name ?